# Problem saving added point to GeoServer WFS-T via OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs-t

I want to add a point and then with `WFS-T`, save this to db.

I work with Openlayers and GeoServer.

```
saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
"WFS Vectore",
{
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        srsName: "EPSG:4326",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iran/wms?service=WFS",
        featureType: "population_utf-8",
        featureNS: "http://iran.kadaster.org",
        geometryName: "geom"
    })
});
```

I add point with two methods:

1.

```
wfs.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) - 180),
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 180) - 90)
    )
)]);
saveStrategy.save();
```

2.

```
var drawFeatureController = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(wfs, OpenLayers.Handler.Point);
```

And then add a point with the mouse:

```
saveStrategy.save();
```

The second method works but the first method doesn't.

I need the first method.

How can I do this?

update:
[image]

Comment: Inspect the http traffic with Fiddler or something similar and add the actual WFS-T request into your question. It may also reveal the difference and solve your problem.

Comment: The payload does not show any content to insert with WFS-T transaction request. You have some demo requests available from GeoServer UI, see example from WFS_transactionInsert.xml. It has wrong coordinates for EPSG:4326 but don't care about it. And use WFS 1.0.0 for getting less troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you add a point with `new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(wfs, OpenLayers.Handler.Point)`, by default feature state set to "Insert" but when you add a point with  `vectorLayer.addFeatures()` command, the feature state is null.

when OpenLayers wants to save change, it see to the state of the feature, and you have to set the added feature state to "Insert"(case-sensitive).

Ok sir?